# How to pick JSON nodes given in an Excel table for each field?

Tags: json, excel, vba

Hi I am quite new to VBA and JSON. I want to parse a JSON script using a VBA macro.

I already have an Excel table with each field and it's corresponding JSON path.

While trying to pick the value from Excel table, it is read as string and, quotes are added in the beginning and end of the string. The quotes `"` in the beginning and the end of the path of the JSON variable makes it impossible to read the value from the JSON script.

For example, if the path is `project->name`, the location in Excel table is `("project")("name")`. But after reading it in VBA it becomes `"("project")("name")"`. With the extra quotes `"` in the path, the location is not getting identified in the VBA code.

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "name": "Basketball",
            "Questions":{
                "question1": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "question2":"Who is your favorite player",}
                   }
                    }
                     }
```

For this JSON script, I have created an Excel table with paths of question1 and question2:

- ("quiz")("sport")("name")("question1")
- ("quiz")("sport")("name")("question2")

The following code runs a loop and identify path of *question1* first and returns "Which one is correct team name in NBA?" and do the same for *question2*.
But, item(path) is returning an empty string while writing the path completely in the code returns the correct value.

```
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonScript) 'Parse Json from GitHub

For Each item In jsonObject("data")      
    For i = 1 To nrow ' loops through rows with path for each field
       Path = ws2.Range("C" & i).Value 'path of each field
       MsgBox item(Path) 'returns Empty
       question1 = item("quiz")("sport")("name")("question1") 'returns question1 value:Which one is correct team name in NBA?  
    Next   
Next
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply in that way particularly with the `()`. You can have the paths, as a comma separated list of path elements (no spaces), in the sheet and do the following.
You also need to remove the additional `","` after player.

Note: I am testing the `UBound` of the array generated by the split on the `","` of the string read in from the sheet and held in the array (`arr`) at the current index `i`. This ensures I apply the write nested syntax to retrieve the required value.

I am not sure where you are getting `"data"` from. I can't see it in the string provided. You would amend according to your actual JSON if different.

---

**Data:**

[image]

---

Output:

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Dim json As Object, jsonSource  As String, paths(), i As Long, ws As Worksheet, arr() As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    jsonSource = ws.[C1]

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonSource)
    paths = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A3").Value)

    For i = LBound(paths) To UBound(paths)
        arr = Split(paths(i), ",")
        Select Case UBound(arr)
        Case 2
            Debug.Print json(arr(0))(arr(1))(arr(2))
        Case 3
            Debug.Print json(arr(0))(arr(1))(arr(2))(arr(3))
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**JSON string in C1:**

```
{ "quiz": { "sport": { "name": "Basketball", "Questions":{ "question1": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?", "question2":"Who is your favorite player"} } } }
```

Comment: Hi, this helped me a lot :)  Also, if there is an array in the JSon script, how can I add it in the excel table to call it in a loop?

Comment: Do you mean a collection? If so, you will need to provide the index in the comma separated list.

Comment: Also, the data was part of the original script. The one I pasted was a sample one I got from internet.

Comment: {
"id":"abcd125",
"basicdetails":[
{
"name":"Thomas",
"age":25
},
{
"name":"John",
"age":32
},
{
"name":"Michael",
"age":23}]}

Comment: In this script, basic details is an array with size 3, I was trying to run a loop to extract values from this. I added in the lookup table basicdetails(k),name; where k is the  counter for the array position. But this is returning type mismatch.

Comment: If you are expecting to use an index you will need to convert to integer/long the value read in from sheet. You would then need to further develop your Select Case as you will have cases where arr(n) might be a need to be an integer (for array/collection) or string (dictionary)

Comment: Debug.Print json(arr(0))(Int(arr(1)))(arr(2))  and basicdetails,1,name
  in A1

Comment: I was trying the following for the lookup:  basicdetails,k,name. But this is returning "Type Mismatch" with the following command: Debug.Print JSon(arr(0))(Int(arr(1)))(arr(2))

Comment: what is k in this context?

Comment: The code I am trying is For k=1 to size_array Debug.Print Json(arr(0)(Int(arr(1)))arr(2)) .

Comment: k won't be a variable. It will come out as a string and remain as the letter "k" not an index. You would want something like Json(arr(0)(k)(arr(1))

Comment: Yea, but is there a way to fix this. I want to explicitly write the locations of JSON variables in a sheet and use it to get the value. I am not sure how to do this for arrays.

Comment: Cool will try this. Thanks :)

Comment: You would use either of the two methods I mention. Either have the  number in the sheet e.g. 1 and convert with int when read in. Or have the variable k in your code and your sheet path would not include k in the comma separated list and you would adjust your indexes for arr accordingly (as one  less index) - or strictly speaking - it would be picked up in a different Case of the Select Case as the UBound would have changed.

Comment: Hey That helped, I am running it in a loop as a separate condition. Thank you! :)